# permutation: seven boys and 4 girls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are seven boys and four girls at a dance in how many ways can they form couples to dance if all the girls have partner?

Can someone teach me how to solve this?

Comment: Need clarification: how many couples can be formed, what do the girls partner with, etc.

Comment: Wait, you just asked a very similar question $20$ minutes ago concerning permutations.... is this homework?? Anyway, what have you attempted thus far?

Comment: How do you define a couple? boy-girl pair?

Comment: @Useless haha thinking outside of the box...

Comment: the girls partner with the boys @ParclyTaxel

Comment: Yes, what do the remaining boys partner with? And what have you tried on the problem?

Comment: partner with the other 4 girls.. if u teach me how to solve permutations and combinations I can go ahead and solve this one..

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar this problem is completely equivalent to the previous one, you should learn the general principle (i.e. Rule of Product) to see how solve this kind of combinatorial problem instead of learn blind formulas to use without understand why they work.

Comment: @gimusi thanks! that is why I asked again,because I did not understand the formula before

Comment: You have a location $B$ (for boys) and a location $G$ (for girls). In location $G$, there are four hotels that you want to go to in order to stay for the night. These hotels are $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ and $g_4$. Now from $B$, there are seven different ways to get to each hotel.

Therefore there are $7\times 4$ paths in total from $B$ to $G$, namely $28$ paths. And thus there exist $28$ paths from $G$ to $B$, so we do $28\times 28$ and now we add $28\times \,$(total number of locations under investigation). 
This makes $$28^2 + 28\times 2 = 28(28 + 2) = 28\times 30 = 840.$$

Comment: I don’t know why, but I seem to get the answer to some questions like these from this little method I came up with on my own $\uparrow$

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar indeed it is important to understand the basic principle at first and then the formulas, be sure that the Rule of Product is the  the "fundamental principle of counting", you really need to keep it mind before of any formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

- 7 choices for the first girl
- 6 choices for the second girl
- 5 choices for the third girl
- 4 choices for the fourth girl

Now apply the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to obtain

$$7\cdot 6 \cdot 5\cdot 4=840$$

(just as the previous problem)

Comment: How many ways to form groups of three? Just curious...

Comment: @user477343 group of three with only one girl? you need another boy!

Comment: Groups of three with one girl only.... or ideally, groups of boys and girls, the amount of girls and boys varying between $1$, $2$, and $3$. I want to test my method of finding the answer to these problems. I invented a method which seems to work for questions like these, but only with groups of two and not above.

Comment: @user477343 If we have 8 boys we have bin(8,2) choices for the first girl bin(6,2) for the second bin(4,2) for the third and one for the fourth thus in total 8!/2^4=2520. Let formulate an OP for different questions!

Answer (score 0):

So you have 4 girls. Assume the girls choose a partner each (one after the other), i.e. girl A chooses a partner first (she has 7 possible choices). Then girl B goes ahead and chooses one of the remaining 6 boys). Following are girls C and D.

Remember, that girl B has 6 choices left, no matter which of the boys girl A chose before here, so there are $7\times 6=42$ possible partner combinations of girl A and girl B with any of the boys.

This implies that in total you will have $7\times 6\times 5\times 4=840$ ways to form couples.